# data sequence handing

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck with a weird problem of handling data sequences.
My source data looks like -

```
Roll-on, Marker
  1,1
  2,0
  3,0
  5,1
  8,1
  9,0
 10,1
```

the marker column can only have two values, 1 and 0

if the roll no column is in a sequence, the marker value of 1 indicates the start of the sequence and all the remaining roll no will have marker value 0 within that sequence. So for roll no sequence 1-3, marker value is 1 for roll no 1 and 0 for the rest. However, if roll no doesn't fall into a sequence(as in roll no 8), the marker value is 1.
From this data I need to create an output as follows -

```
Roll range
 1
 2
 3
 1-3
 5
 5-5
 8
 9
10
 8-10
```

Meaning -

- display the roll no in sequence as in the input
- after each sequence ends, display a new record containing the start and end roll no of the proceeding sequence

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: The tag `sql` says: "...and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used." **Please correct the tags**

Comment: What did you try yourself? Can you share how your tables are created?  Can you explain `8-10` ? ( Because 8 was not "in a sequence" )

Comment: Why did you want to get `8-10` instead of `8-9` and `10-10`? because there are two `Marker`

Comment: It's an interesting problem but is the a real-world problem you are trying to solve? Or is it an exercise.

Comment: @ D Shih - it's a typo. you can consider roll 11 instead of 10 to break the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN a=2 AND CHARINDEX('-',R)=0 THEN CONCAT(R,'-',R) ELSE R END as R, 
   R2, 
   a
FROM (
   SELECT 
      1 as a,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), Roll) R, 
      Roll as R2
   FROM table1
   
   UNION ALL
   
   SELECT
      2,
      STRING_AGG(Roll,'-') R,
      MAX(Roll) as R2
   FROM (
      SELECT
         Roll,
         SUM(Marker) OVER (ORDER BY Roll) S
      FROM
         table1
         ) x 
   GROUP BY S
) x

ORDER BY R2,a
```

output:

| R | R2 | a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 1-2-3 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 5-5 | 5 | 2 |
| 8 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 9 | 1 |
| 8-9 | 9 | 2 |
| 10 | 10 | 1 |
| 10-10 | 10 | 2 |

- Columns `R2` and `a` are added for correct sorting.
- I group `8-9` and `10-10`, but this question is still open, see comment

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an island and gap problem.

If I understand correctly, we can try to use `SUM` window function with conditions to make it.

Generator a gap of row number then getting `min` and `max` group by

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(Roll),'-',MAX(Roll))
FROM (
 SELECT *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Marker = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY Roll) grp
 FROM T
) t1
GROUP BY grp
```

as I comment I am not sure about the logic of `8-10` (why isn't `8-9` and `10-10`) from your expect result and columns description, I think we can try to judge `Max` of Roll then do some arithmetic.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MIN(Roll),'-',MAX(Roll))
FROM (
 SELECT *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Marker = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY Roll) + IIF(MAX(Roll) OVER() = Roll, - Marker,0) grp
 FROM T
) t1
GROUP BY grp
```

so that the final query combines result set we can use `UNION ALL`

```
;WITH CTE AS (
 SELECT *,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Marker = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY Roll) + IIF(MAX(Roll) OVER() = Roll, - Marker,0) grp
 FROM T
)
SELECT [Roll range]
FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(MIN(Roll),'-',MAX(Roll)) 'Roll range',MAX(Roll) seq
  FROM CTE t1
  GROUP BY grp
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST(Roll AS VARCHAR(5)),Roll
  FROM CTE t1
) t1
ORDER BY seq
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fa79fd7d00036bcc4a2c9c3eb448abec)